# How early can I pass security in Brussels airport?

Tags: airports, airport-transfer, airport-security

I have a really early flight at Brussels airport (departure around 7 AM).

The only public transport that I can get leaves me at the airport at 3 AM). I will have the check in already done.
Can I pass security and go to the airside at that time?

The other option is to go earlier (and arrive around 10 PM, previous day). Would I be allowed to enter the airside?

Comment: I've got no experience with Brussels airport but usually airlines only open their check-in desks a maximum of 3-3,5 hours before a flight. You'll likely have to spend some time in the departures hall waiting for the check-in desk for your flight to open.

Comment: I usually go to the airport many hours before and enjoy the lounge, but then I've already checked in online and I only have a carry-on. 4 hours shouldn't be any problem at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted Brussels airport on their Facebook messenger.

Their response was that yes, you can go through earlier if that works for you, HOWEVER, it does depend on whether or not you have checked luggage, as some checkin counters won't open earlier.

[image]